Stripe hosted checkout with quantity input on html side
I am building a checkout app and need the quantity selector on the html side and pass that quantity to the checkout page. I do not want the quantity selector on the checkout page.
Following stripes doc https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/quickstart?lang=php there is nothing that explains that.

You can achieve this by setting line_items.adjustable_quantity.enabled to false and passing in the quantity collected from your frontend to line_items.quantity.

Are you able to provide an example of how this will look?
